# How to alert the user about the due date of an unpaid invoice in OpenERP 7?

Tags: odoo

I am working with OpenERP V7. I want to know how OpenERP can alert a user that the due date of an unpaid invoice is today or after x days ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use account_followup module. Its a base module available in OpenERP 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the account_credit_control community module, available in the Account Financial Tools project on Launchpad.

https://launchpad.net/account-financial-tools